# is destructor called implicitly when declared in the class and an object is created in main?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
   public:
   A();//code for constructor
   ~A();//code for destructor
}
int main(){
{
  A a= new A();
  delete a;
}
```

where does the following code throw an error.. is ~A() called implicitly just like constructor or the object "a" is deleted in the main function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What error does it throw*? That code won't even compile.

Comment: Did you mean `A* a = ...`?

Comment: There is a couple of issue that stand out, you are missing a `;` after the class definition and `a` needs to be a pointer `A *a` Also assuming this is supposed to be a complete example you ctor and dtor needs a body.

Comment: The answer to your question title is yes. Your code does not accurately reflect the question.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your code is corrected to the following:

```
class A
{
   public:
   A();//code for constructor
   ~A();//code for destructor
};
int main()
{
  A *a= new A();
  delete a;
}
```

The destructor is called by delete before delete frees the memory the object occupied.

If your code put a on the stack, like the following:

```
class A
{
   public:
   A();//code for constructor
   ~A();//code for destructor
};
int main()
{
  A a;
} // <---- Here
```

The destructor would be called before the closing brace of the enclosing scope.  In this case the enclosing scope is the function main.

But if a were created inside another block, like the following:

```
class A
{
   public:
   A();//code for constructor
   ~A();//code for destructor
};
int main()
{
  if( 1 == 1 )
  {
      A a;
      // Do something with a
  } // <---- Here
}
```

The destructor would be called just before the closing block of the if block.  The same goes for anywhere you create a block.  Inside a for loop, while loop or even if you just put braces around a block of code.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't know why people are voting up answers that are just comments on coding errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare constructor and destructor you must define them too. Otherwise the compiler will come up with some errors. Yours are just declared...

Example:

```
class test
{
public:
    test() {}  //declared and defined
    ~test() {}  //declared and defined
}
```

Comment: Class definition need a `;` at the end and you should also mention the other two issues with the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 errors in this code:

1. Class definition should end with a `;`
2. Constructor and destructor should have at least a blank implementation
3. Whenever you allocate memory using `new`, it should be assigned to a pointer

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @cppcode and would have wrote the same.

But I would add the  line

```
A a= new A();
```

should be

```
A *a= new A;
```

Alternatively do not declare constructor/destructor. C++ will do that work for you!

Answer (score 0):

new operator return a pointer to that type you write to front new operator thus you must put it in a pointer that it type must be equal to object type or at least pointer type must be base of object type.
and when you use delete operator the destructor of main object call.

excuse me for my bad english.